# Connect jupyter to hive metastore

Tags: jupyter-notebook, hive-metastore

I'm using a jupyter notebook on docker
In my spark conf folder (/usr/local/spark/conf) i have my hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://metastore-uri:9083</value>
  </property>
</configuration
```

when i use a R notebook the following code works ok and connect to the remote hive metastore

```
library(SparkR)
as <- sparkR.session("local[*]")
sql("show tables")
```

but when i run in a scala notebook the following code

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);    
sqlContext.sql("show tables").show
```

it starts locally the metastore and shows no data

any tip?